# Implementing toolbar invoking null object reference

Tags: java, android, xml

I am having problems implementing the actionbar (which I think is now replaced by toolbar).  What I want is a small drop down menu with the 3 dots where I can have a few options such as settings and credits. I have tried to set it up so that the menu appears on the homelistview.java page.  I feel like I have been going in circles trying different solutions and getting a new error each time and it always points back to the same location mentioned below.

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

I had originally thought it was because I didn't include             setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); but it was not happy including 2 content views.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code.

styles.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

--------------- menu_main.xml-------------------

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="cs495capstone.edu.bsu.myapplication.MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_credits"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_credits"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_lovely"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_lovely"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

--------------activity_main.xml ----------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="cs495capstone.edu.bsu.myapplication.HomeActivityListview">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/activity_add_appointment" />
<include layout="@layout/activity_add_history" />
<include layout="@layout/activity_appointments" />
<include layout="@layout/activity_dog_profile" />
<include layout="@layout/activity_history" />
<include layout="@layout/activity_home" />
<include layout="@layout/activity_home_activity_listview" />
<include layout="@layout/activity_login" />
<include layout="@layout/activity_new_dog" />
<include layout="@layout/activity_registration" />
<include layout="@layout/activity_splash_screen" />
<include layout="@layout/activity_update_dog" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

----------------------- homeactivitylistview.xml-------------------------

```
public class HomeActivityListview extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView lv;
    Context context;
    ArrayList dogName;
    ArrayList dogID;
    public static int [] dogImages={R.drawable.dogpic};
    public static String [] dogNames={};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_activity_listview);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        context=this;

        lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, dogImages));
    }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


public void sendProfile(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DogProfileActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    public void NumberOne(View view) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDlg.setMessage("Confirm Dog went number one");
        alertDlg.setCancelable(false);

        alertDlg.setPositiveButton("Confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //HomeActivity.super.onBackPressed();
            }
        });

        alertDlg.setNegativeButton("Change", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //HomeActivity.super.onBackPressed();
            }
        });
        alertDlg.create().show();

    }
    public void NumberTwo(View view) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDlg.setMessage("Confirm Dog went number two");
        alertDlg.setCancelable(false);

        alertDlg.setPositiveButton("Confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //HomeActivity.super.onBackPressed();
            }
        });

        alertDlg.setNegativeButton("Change", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //HomeActivity.super.onBackPressed();
            }
        });
        alertDlg.create().show();

    }

    public void AddNewDog(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewDogActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

------------------ main_activity.java -----------------

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

--------------homelistview.java------------------

```
public class HomeActivityListview extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView lv;
    Context context;
    ArrayList dogName;
    ArrayList dogID;
    public static int [] dogImages={R.drawable.dogpic};
    public static String [] dogNames={};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_activity_listview);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        context=this;

        lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, dogImages));
    }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


public void sendProfile(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DogProfileActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    public void NumberOne(View view) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDlg.setMessage("Confirm Dog went number one");
        alertDlg.setCancelable(false);

        alertDlg.setPositiveButton("Confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //HomeActivity.super.onBackPressed();
            }
        });

        alertDlg.setNegativeButton("Change", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //HomeActivity.super.onBackPressed();
            }
        });
        alertDlg.create().show();

    }
    public void NumberTwo(View view) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDlg.setMessage("Confirm Dog went number two");
        alertDlg.setCancelable(false);

        alertDlg.setPositiveButton("Confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //HomeActivity.super.onBackPressed();
            }
        });

        alertDlg.setNegativeButton("Change", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //HomeActivity.super.onBackPressed();
            }
        });
        alertDlg.create().show();

    }

    public void AddNewDog(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewDogActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

---------------androidmanifest-----------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="cs495capstone.edu.bsu.doggydid" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".SplashScreenActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".RegistrationActivity"
        android:label="Registration" />
    <activity
        android:name=".NewDogActivity"
        android:label="Dog Information" />
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="Login" />
    <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home" />
    <activity
        android:name=".DogProfileActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_dog_profile" />
    <activity
        android:name=".HistoryActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_records" />
    <activity
        android:name=".addHistoryActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_add_record" />
    <activity
        android:name=".EventsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_events" />
    <activity
        android:name=".addEventsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_add_events" />
    <activity
        android:name=".UpdateDogActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_update_dog" />
    <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivityListview"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home_activity_listview"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

-----------------------Error Readout--------------------

04-14 13:35:36.905 3117-3117/cs495capstone.edu.bsu.doggydid E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: cs495capstone.edu.bsu.doggydid, PID: 3117
                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{cs495capstone.edu.bsu.doggydid/cs495capstone.edu.bsu.doggydid.HomeActivityListview}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.getTitle()' on a null object reference
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.getTitle()' on a null object reference
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:98)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:91)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar.(ToolbarActionBar.java:73)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:205)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:99)
                                                                                  at cs495capstone.edu.bsu.doggydid.HomeActivityListview.onCreate(HomeActivityListview.java:31)
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)

Comment: It looks like you are setting a `Toolbar` in both `HomeActivityListview` and `MainActivity`. The XML file that you pasted appears to be the layout file for `HomeActivityListview` judging by this line `tools:context="cs495capstone.edu.bsu.myapplication.HomeActivityListview"`. Can you verify that `activity_main.xml` contains a `Toolbar` with an `id` of "R.id.toolbar"?

Comment: This may be it looking at the new project that has a toolbar as a custom appbar layout and toolbar, then looking at mine editing the xml didnt create those.  and its being stubborn when I try to add them in design view

Comment: Yeah, 'Design' mode can be a little clunky. I recommend using the 'Text' edit mode for XML files whenever you need to make a change.

Comment: Ya it was the reverse this time design mode wasn't including the custom views or toolbars in the design.  While the text edit mode had all the code for them.

Answer (score 0):

Your Toolbar toolbar is declared/ initialized in the onCreate only, hence the scope is gone out of that method...

define the object as an activity variable and initialize it in the `onCreate`

```
public class HomeActivityListview extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView lv;
    Context context;
    ArrayList dogName;
    ArrayList dogID;
    public static int [] dogImages={R.drawable.dogpic};
    public static String [] dogNames={};
    private Toolbar toolbar;  //define it  here
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_activity_listview);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);  //but init here
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        context=this;

        lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, dogImages));
    }
```

Comment: If I remove the Toolbar in Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewByID(R.id.toolbar); it throws an error and wants me to initialize it there adding the Toolbar back in

Comment: how are you removing it??

Comment: Ended up figuring it out.  In my activity_main xml class I had only coded in the xml and when I viewed in design mode it wasn't showing the appbarlayout or toolbar options